# Why the Hamiltonian is constant along the integral curves of the hamiltonian vector field?

Tags: symplectic-geometry

Let $H$ the Hamiltonian of a system and $\gamma $ an integral curve of the Hamiltonian vector field, i.e. if $\gamma (t)=(q(t),p(t))$ and $H(p,q)$ is the Hamiltonian, then $$\begin{cases} \dot p=-H_q\\ \dot q= H_p\end{cases}.$$

In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_vector_field#Properties) the say that $H$ is constant along $\gamma $. Why is this true ? i.e. why $H(\gamma (t))$ is constant ?

Answer (score 3):

For $H(p,q,t) = H(p(t),q(t))$ think that

$$
\frac{d}{dt}H(p(t),q(t)) = H_p \dot p + H_q \dot q
$$

Comment: Indeed, it make sense :) But I'm confusion with wikipedia notation, what they mean by $<dH,\dot \gamma >=0$ ? Because $\omega $ is not a scalar product (is not a riemann manifold)

Comment: It's the pairing by evaluation between a covector and a vector (or if you wish one-form on the curve and a vector field along the curve).